# Add minutes to an Oracle date

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I am trying to add minutes to my sql but no error and no data.

This is my sql

```
select distinct mo.reference_no payment_id, mo.dcn message_id,
mo.amount, mo.ccy, decode (mo.msg_status, 'R', 'Repair', 'P',
'Processed','N','Ungenerated','G','Generated',mo.msg_status)
message_status, to_char 
(MO.INSERT_TIME,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
paym_date, mo.branch_date, mo.maker_id 
from table1 mo
left join table2 mi 
on mo.reference_no = mi.generated_ref_no 
where mo.swift_msg_type = 103
and mo.ccy = 'XXX' and mo.branch_date = trunc(sysdate)
and mo.msg_status in('R','N','G','P')
order by PAYM_DATE desc;
```

And I want to add 5 minutes to (MO.INSERT_TIME,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')

So I want my sql show me after 5 minutes for this column (MO.INSERT_TIME,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')

I wrote sql like that

```
select distinct mo.reference_no payment_id, mo.dcn message_id,
mo.amount, mo.ccy, decode (mo.msg_status, 'R', 'Repair', 'P',
'Processed','N','Ungenerated','G','Generated',mo.msg_status)
message_status, to_char 
(MO.INSERT_TIME,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
paym_date, mo.branch_date, mo.maker_id 
from table1 mo
left join table2 mi 
on mo.reference_no = mi.generated_ref_no 
where mo.swift_msg_type = 103
and mo.ccy = 'XXX' and mo.branch_date = trunc(sysdate)
and MO.INSERT_TIME = to_date (sysdate,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') + INTERVAL '5' MINUTE
and mo.msg_status in('R','N','G','P')
order by PAYM_DATE desc;
```

And after 5 minutes I am selecting this sql and their is no data. Can you explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you used:

```
and MO.INSERT_TIME = to_date (sysdate,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') + INTERVAL '5' MINUTE
```

It is wrong because you're applying `TO_DATE` function to `SYSDATE` which already returns `DATE` datatype, so there's no point in doing it.

---

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> select sysdate,
  2         sysdate + interval '5' minute
  3  from dual;

SYSDATE             SYSDATE+INTERVAL'5'
------------------- -------------------
10.01.2023 09:49:05 10.01.2023 09:54:05

SQL>
```

It is probably not very likely that `MO.INSERT_TIME` will *exactly*  be the same as `SYSDATE` (which is *right now*) + 5 minutes, which is in the future.

Perhaps you'd rather set that condition to e.g. *rows inserted during last 5 minutes* (which makes more sense to me):

```
and MO.INSERT_TIME >= sysdate - INTERVAL '5' MINUTE
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you very much for your solution tip. It really helped me to figure out my SQL.
If I use ''and MO.INSERT_TIME >= sysdate - INTERVAL '5' MINUTE'' - it will show me sysdate too. But I don't want to see last 3 minutes. So I used 'between'. And it works exactly how I want

''and MO.INSERT_TIME between sysdate - INTERVAL '15' MINUTE and sysdate - INTERVAL '3' MINUTE''

Comment: You're welcome; I'm glad you made it work.

Answer (score 0):

DATE + NUMBER where number can be fractional and is interpreted as days, and a minute is 1/(24*60) of a day...